# Java script функции

Tags: javascript, функции

В ресторане принято оставлять чаевые 15% от суммы заказа. Напишите функцию percentageValue, которая принимает два аргумента: number и percent и возвращает процент от числа.

Comment: для начала изучите тему процентов.... как они считаются в математике, на бумаге, а не программировании?

Comment: function percentageValue(number, percent){
return number / 100 * percent;
}

Comment: по ситаксису все правильно ? @АлексейШиманский

Comment: да, уже правильно

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, свой код оформляйте в виде текста, а не картинки. Иначе (с большой долей вероятности) он будет удалён, как не представляющий ценности для поиска.

Что касается вашей головной боли, то здесь, как я вижу, дело не в JavaScript, а в невозможности решить задачу из банальной школьной программы.

Вот простейший пример:

```
function percentageValue(number, percent) {
    return number / 100 * percent;
}

console.log(percentageValue(100, 15))
console.log(percentageValue(200, 15))
```

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: Спасибо не мне, а всем, кто прокомментировал, так как мы одновременно написали здесь и решение есть  и в комментариях. Если вы хотите достойно принимать участие в проекте, то отредактируйте код, или вопрос удалят. А вы получите минус.

Comment: Исправил, спасибо большое, ребят